# Cannot start aftpd correctly through init.d

Tags: debian, embedded-linux, init

I try to start `aftpd` on a Debian 8 board.

I've installed `aftpd` package which automatically created the Following `/etc/init.d/aftpd` starting script:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# This is an init script for openembedded
# Copy it to /etc/init.d/atftpd and type
# > update-rc.d atftpd defaults 60
#


test -f /usr/sbin/atftpd || exit 0

test -d /srv/tftp || mkdir -p /srv/tftp

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting tftp daemon: atftpd"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec /usr/sbin/atftpd --daemon --port 69 
    echo "."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping tftp daemon: atftpd"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --exec /usr/sbin/atftpd
    echo "."
    ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal 1 --exec /usr/sbin/atftpd
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 1
        $0 start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/atftpd {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

But when then machine starts I get the Following error message:

```
Starting tftp daemon: atftpdstart-stop-daemon: unrecognized option '--daemon'
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2018-11-21 22:38:19 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: start-stop-daemon [OPTIONS] [-S|-K] ... [-- ARGS...]
.
```

it seems that `start-stop-daemon` takes `--daemon` for him.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `--` to separate arguments for the executable. Quoting the [man page of start-stop-daemon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html):

> Any arguments given after -- on the command line are passed unmodified to the program being started.

The arguments are passed "as usual". As there is whitespace right after `/usr/sbin/atftpd`, the rest is passed to `start-stop-daemon` in a standard way.